# Customizing the access log filename's suffix

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, logging

I have a springboot application which server access logs are enabled. by default, the name is generated as

```
access_log.2020-01-17.log
```

But want the date at the end as

```
access_log.log.2020-01-17
```

I tried this but its not working

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd.HH-mm}
```

Comment: Does the log suffix not changed at all? Or dates are empty in filename?

Comment: @AndriyBudzinskyy it got changed but access_log.2020-01-17.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd.HH-mm}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bypass **suffix** and make a small change in **prefix**

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=
server.tomcat.accesslog.prefix=access_log.log
server.tomcat.accesslog.file-date-format=.yyyy-MM-dd
```

**Result**

access_log.log.2020-01-17